# ssh does not start, bad configuration option

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

When i try to start the ssh `systemctl start ssh` i got the following error

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The result that i got after the `systemctl status ssh.service` are

```
> ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)   
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-07-16 12:40:33 EEST;
> 1min 33s ago
>      Docs: man:sshd(8)
>            man:sshd_config(5)   Process: 29636 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
> 
> Jul 16 12:40:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service
> RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart. Jul 16 12:40:33
> raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart
> counter is at 5. Jul 16 12:40:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped
> OpenBSD Secure Shell server. Jul 16 12:40:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]:
> ssh.service: Start request repeated too quickly. Jul 16 12:40:33
> raspberrypi systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Jul 16 12:40:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure
> Shell server.
```

I try the `sshd -t` command and result are following

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 122: Bad configuration option: net.core.netdev_max_backlog
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

and the value is `net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 3000`

I try to unistall - reinstall ssh nothing happent
any ideas what to do please? Thank you

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: I am sorry, i see that some other ask question about ssh too, what i have to do to ask unix & linux user please?

Comment: Just go over there and post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.core.netdev_max_backlog` should not be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but in `/etc/sysctl.conf`